# Using "with_nested" on two subelements to iterate every elements in two different type of list/dict variables?

Tags: ansible

I have two different types of variables as detailed below. My ansible yml file below can process the first type of data structure(variable), but not able to process the 2nd type. Below is my yml file

```yaml
- name: print volumes
  hosts: localhost

  vars:

    volumes:
      - volumename: volume1
        client:
          - 1.1.1.1
          - 1.1.1.2
      - volumename: volume2
        client:
          - 2.2.2.2
      - volumename: volume3
        client:
          - 3.3.3.3

  tasks:

    - name: display volumes
      debug:
        msg: "volume: {{ item.0.volumename }} client: {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ volumes|subelements('client') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.volumename }}"
```

the code above didn't work for the second type of variable:

```yaml
vars:
  volumename:
    - volume1
    - volume2
    - volume3
  client:
    - 1.1.1.1
    - 1.1.1.2
```

Expected results for the second variable:

```
volume1 --> 1.1.1.1
volume2 --> 1.1.1.1
volume3 --> 1.1.1.1
volume1 --> 1.1.1.2
volume2 --> 1.1.1.2
volume3 --> 1.1.1.2
```

I tried "with_nested" as below, but it didn't work:

```yaml
    with_nested:
      - "{{ volumes|subelements('client') }}"
      - "{{ volumes|subelements('volumename') }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for the [`product`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/product_filter.html) filter!

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    volumename:
      - volume1
      - volume2
      - volume3
    client:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 1.1.1.2
  tasks:
    - name: display volumes
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.1 }} --> {{ item.0 }}"
      loop: "{{ client|product(volumename) }}"
```

Running the above playbook produces:

```
TASK [display volumes] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['1.1.1.1', 'volume1']) => {
    "msg": "volume1 --> 1.1.1.1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['1.1.1.1', 'volume2']) => {
    "msg": "volume2 --> 1.1.1.1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['1.1.1.1', 'volume3']) => {
    "msg": "volume3 --> 1.1.1.1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['1.1.1.2', 'volume1']) => {
    "msg": "volume1 --> 1.1.1.2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['1.1.1.2', 'volume2']) => {
    "msg": "volume2 --> 1.1.1.2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['1.1.1.2', 'volume3']) => {
    "msg": "volume3 --> 1.1.1.2"
}
```

If we grep out all the extraneous bits, that's:

```
    "msg": "volume1 --> 1.1.1.1"
    "msg": "volume2 --> 1.1.1.1"
    "msg": "volume3 --> 1.1.1.1"
    "msg": "volume1 --> 1.1.1.2"
    "msg": "volume2 --> 1.1.1.2"
    "msg": "volume3 --> 1.1.1.2"
```

Comment: Your code works for the 2nd type of variable. But, how can one same code works for the first type of variable? 
 vars:
    volumename:
      - volume1
    client:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 1.1.1.2
    volumename:
      - volume2
    client:
      - 2.2.2.2
    volumename:
      - volume3
    client:
      - 3.3.3.3

Comment: You wouldn't generally expect the same code to work with two completely different data structures. You would either write a couple of different tasks, or stick with a single data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use the filter [*default*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.default) if you don't know what data you get

```yaml
  volumes|d(dict(volumename|d([])|
                 product([client|d([])]))|
            dict2items(key_name='volumename',
                       value_name='client'))
```

The same structure is created from the lists *volumename* and *client* if the list *volumes* is not defined  You can use it in the loop. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.volumename }} --> {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ volumes|d(dict(volumename|d([])|
                               product([client|d([])]))|
                          dict2items(key_name='volumename',
                                     value_name='client'))|
                        subelements('client') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.volumename }}"
```

- If you provide the list *volumes*

```yaml
shell> cat volumes.yml 
volumes:
  - volumename: volume1
    client:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 1.1.1.2
  - volumename: volume2
    client:
      - 2.2.2.2
  - volumename: volume3
    client:
      - 3.3.3.3
```

the debug gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e @volumes.yml

  ...

  msg: volume1 --> 1.1.1.1
  msg: volume1 --> 1.1.1.2
  msg: volume2 --> 2.2.2.2
  msg: volume3 --> 3.3.3.3
```

- If you provide the lists *volumename* and *client* instead

```yaml
shell> cat volumename_client.yml 
volumename:
  - volume1
  - volume2
  - volume3
client:
  - 1.1.1.1
  - 1.1.1.2
```

the debug gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e @volumename_client.yml

  ...

  msg: volume1 --> 1.1.1.1
  msg: volume1 --> 1.1.1.2
  msg: volume2 --> 1.1.1.1
  msg: volume2 --> 1.1.1.2
  msg: volume3 --> 1.1.1.1
  msg: volume3 --> 1.1.1.2
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ volumes|d(dict(volumename|d([])|
                                product([client|d([])]))|
                           dict2items(key_name='volumename',
                                      value_name='client')) }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.volumename }} --> {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ volumes|d(dict(volumename|d([])|
                               product([client|d([])]))|
                          dict2items(key_name='volumename',
                                     value_name='client'))|
                        subelements('client') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.volumename }}"
```

- There will be no iteration if you don't provide any data

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************

TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: []

TASK [debug] *************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]
```

- Optionally, put the expression into the *vars* and use it as needed. For example, in the first task simply iterate one attribute only and use the results in the second task

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    my_volumes: "{{ volumes|d(dict(volumename|d([])|
                                   product([client|d([])]))|
                              dict2items(key_name='volumename',
                                         value_name='client')) }}"
    export_info_dict: "{{ dict(export_info.results|
                               json_query('[].[item.volumename, @]')) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.volumename }}"
      loop: "{{ my_volumes }}"
      register: export_info

    - debug:
        var: export_info_dict

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ item.0.volumename }}
          {{ item.1 }}
          {{ export_info_dict[item.0.volumename] }}
      loop: "{{ my_volumes|subelements('client') }}"
```

Comment: Your code works very well. But, I don't fully understand, and difficult for me to apply to my real code. I hate to ask you but,if it is not too much trouble for you, could you please apply your code to mine, then the same code can handle both type of variables? I post my code in the answer.

Comment: I fixed your answer. You should put it into your question and proceed there. Then delete your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  collections:
    - netapp.ontap
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    login: &login
      hostname: "10.192.18.10"
      username: "admin"
      password: "netapp123"
      https: true
      validate_certs: false

  vars_files:
    - ./var_files_dir/volumes.yml

  tasks:

    - name: Get the name of vserver/svm and export_policy upon the volume
      netapp.ontap.na_ontap_rest_info:
        use_python_keys: true
        use_rest: Always
        gather_subset:
          - storage/volumes
        fields:
          - 'svm.name'
          - 'nas.export_policy.name'
        parameters:
          name: "{{ item.0.volumename }}"
        <<: *login
      loop: "{{ volumes|d(dict(volumename|d([])|
                               product([client|d([])]))|
                          dict2items(key_name='volumename',
                                     value_name='client'))|
                        subelements('client', skip_missing=True) }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.volumename }}"
      register: export_info

    - debug:
        var: export_info.results

    - name: Create export-policy rules
      netapp.ontap.na_ontap_export_policy_rule:
        state: present
        client_match: "{{ item.item.1 }}"
        name: "{{ item.ontap_info.storage_volumes.records.0.nas.export_policy.name }}"
        vserver: "{{ item.ontap_info.storage_volumes.records.0.svm.name }}"
        ro_rule: sys
        rw_rule: sys
        protocol: nfs
        super_user_security: sys
        ntfs_unix_security: ignore
        allow_suid: true
        <<: *login
      loop: "{{ export_info.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item.1 }}"
```

Comment: I fixed the functionality of the code. But, the logic is weird. The first task repeats the same *item.0.volumename* iteration for *client*. Post the [mre]  expected results. In the first task, you want to iterate *item.volume*. What should be the result of the iteration in the second task? Post *item.\** only.

Comment: The second task will create export-policy rules upon the module of na_ontap_export_policy_rule upon fields of 'svm.name' and 'nas.export_policy.name'. Each iteration on different volumes will collect corresponding  'svm.name' and 'nas.export_policy.name' upon the module of "na_ontap_rest_info". Will try your code late.

Comment: You still don't understand. We will have to delete this mess. [edit] the question and make it [mre].

Comment: Understand what you said now I think. Because my questions involve a lot of NetApp modules, to be honest, it is challenge for me to follow  "minimal reproducible example", and meanwhile also explain the complicated logic/questions well. You helped me a lot. I will do better next time. Thank you!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).